# carry a message vs. convey a message

Tags: word-choice, collocations

I'm wondering what the difference is between "carry a message" versus "convey a message". Can we use these two expressions interchangeably? Please, comment.I would be very grateful. :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: The two phrases are not identical, but in some context they may be interchangeable. Can you provide a context --like an example sentence or two-- where you think they might be equivalent?

Comment: For example, "The spread of postal services permitted families and friends to convey/carry messages to each other by letter."

Comment: Words can "convey" or "carry" a message in the same sense, but when the subject is people, the meaning doesn't work. If a person "conveys" a message, that means they "communicate" it. But if a person "carries" a message, it means they physically carry it, like delivering a paper letter in an envelope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *some* contexts we might say a communication ***carries*** a message even though it doesn't ***convey*** that message.

For example, suppose the communication is encoded. The message is definitely *present*, but feasibly no recipient actually *receives* the communication - or maybe they receive the text but can't decode it. Most people would agree that no message is *conveyed* in that context.

---

If something (object OR information) is ***carried*** from A to B (two people), the usual implication is it (the object itself, OR the *object containing the information*) was physically passed from A to B. But feasibly B didn't understand (maybe didn't even *read*) the message.

If it's ***conveyed***, then if that "something" is *information*, the usual strong implication is that person B *received **and understood*** the message.